# Timeseries data visuals to show clusters/ groupings

Tags: time-series, cluster-analysis, visualization

I have numerous return time series spanning over a couple of years. I want to see how stable these series are across time. So far I have winsorized and z-scored my data and created histograms and AVG vs. StdDev graphs. Using the histograms I can see how the distribution looks and check for positive or negative skew, with the Avg vs. StdDev chart I tried to get some kind of density measure within the data set (each data point represents a point in time), i.e a big blob means less stable than a dense one

[image: Histogramm]

[image: Density Plot]

I am looking for other ways to visualise my data. Any ideas welcome

Comment: You mentioned this is time series but also that there are numerous entities being measured.  Is avg return the avg for a single entity (e.g. company)?

Comment: The averages are taken over various groups like country, sectors or benchmark, but each chart only covers one type if that makes sense

Comment: What I'm not following is how timeseries plays into it.  For a given country/benchmark (e.g. China population) there are several timepoints.  If there are 20 timepoints are you calculating several returns or only one return?

Comment: Every end of month I calculate 1 return point per category, so for china I would have 12 points for each year etc

Comment: When you take an average for "groups like country" are you using all points?  If China has 50 return points and India has 40 would the average be for 90 points?

Comment: I do one avg for china and one for India each,  I also represent them in 2 separate plots. there is no general country avg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149249/discussion-between-brian-risk-and-markus-london).